# Channeling audio to a particular device

Tags: .net, wpf, audio, directshow

I am developing a WPF based application, which uses DirectShow as well. I need to implement a functionality in which I have to channel audio of video on one of the selected device. To clarify my problem, suppose we have a number of audio devices connected to system, so user must be allowed to play audio from a video file on device selected by him/her. Also how can I enumerate through audio devices connected to a system? I have no idea on how can we channel audio to different devices? I am new to DirectShow development, please help me get through this. Any ideas suggestions are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "to channel", why do you think DirectShow is the API you need? Enumeration is the basic task existing in documnetation for any API, for DirectShow it is here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Roman, I am currently using DirectShow to play audio. What I want to do is to allow users to play audio on their choice of device. I just want to be able to select audio device to play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375473%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> **To enumerate the audio devices available on the user's system**, use the
>   ICreateDevEnum interface with the audio renderer category
>   (CLSID_AudioRendererCategory). For each audio device, the audio
>   renderer category contains two filter instances. One of these
>   corresponds to the DirectSound Renderer, and the other corresponds to
>   the Audio Renderer (WaveOut) filter. The DirectSound instance has the
>   friendly name "DirectSound: DeviceName," where DeviceName is the name
>   of the device. The WaveOut instance has the friendly name DeviceName.
>
> The audio renderer category contains two additional filter instances,
>   named "Default DirectSound Device" and "Default WaveOut Device." These
>   correspond to the default sound device, as chosen by the user through
>   the Control Panel. They are actually mappings to one of the pairs
>   described in the previous paragraph. For example, if the system has
>   two audio devices, Device A and Device B, the audio renderer category
>   will contain the following:

In .NET you have wrapper to this API through [supposedly] DirectShow.NET library.